# Adding attributes with quotation marks – XML in R

Tags: r, xml, loops

I am trying to build an XML file in R using the package XML. (I am very new on that, and I am even still understanding the different components of an XML file, which makes things a little bit more complicated). 
The very first step was quite easy:

```
#Create XML file
doc_beast <- newXMLDoc()
root <- newXMLNode("beast", doc = doc_beast)

#Write taxa node
taxaNode <- newXMLNode("taxa", parent = root, attrs = c(id="taxa"))

taxa <- getNodeSet(doc_beast, "//beast/taxa")

for(i in 1:nrow(metadata)) {
         newXMLNode("taxon", parent = taxa)
        }
doc_beast
```

The output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beast>
  <taxa id="taxa">
    <taxon/>
    <taxon/>
    <taxon/>
  </taxa>
</beast>
```

As you can see, the node 'taxa' has multiple children, which share the same name ('taxon'). But each children is supposed to have distinct attributes. Thus, my pipeline should give an output like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beast>
  <taxa id="taxa">
    <taxon> id="sp_1"/>
    <taxon> id="sp_2"/>
    <taxon> id="sp_3"/>
  </taxa>
</beast>
```

But I can't make it right. I've tried to add a general command inside the loop to extract the good information from a data frame, but I don't know how to do it.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(metadata)) {
         newXMLNode("taxon", parent = taxa, attrs = c(id="i[,1]"))
        }
```

The data frame is something like that:

```
species_name <- c('sp1', 'sp2', 'sp3')
lat <- c(-3.16, -0.56, -2.1)
long <- c(-59.90, -52.57, -60.2)

metadata <- data.frame(species_name,lat,long)
```

I appreciate very much your help.
Many thanks!

L

Comment: Is `<taxon/> id="sp_1">` supposed to be `<taxon id="sp_1"/>`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `newXMLNode`, you can pass an `attrs=` property to set attributes on the node.  So you can do

```
for(i in 1:nrow(metadata)) {
  newXMLNode("taxon", parent = taxa, 
    attrs = list(id=as.character(metadata$species_name[i])))
}
```

This will return

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beast>
  <taxa id="taxa">
    <taxon id="sp1"/>
    <taxon id="sp2"/>
    <taxon id="sp3"/>
  </taxa>
</beast>
```